# Is there a global, persistent CMD history?

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, history, command

Sometimes I forget how the exact syntax of a CMD command looks and then I would like to search my own CMD history. Clearly, within the same session, you can browse it with the up and down arrow keys but what about the history of former CMD sessions? Is there a file, a log the history gets written to or does it all go to digital Nirvana?

Thanks!

Comment: You can hijack the exit command to automatically save a log before exiting: `doskey exit=doskey /history ^>^> C:\path\to\cmdhistory.log $T exit $*` but you'll need to figure out how to execute this automatically at each command prompt session startup. **PS:** Make sure the path of the log file is writable. `C:\ ` is not writable for a non-admin command prompt.

Comment: @ADTC: AutoRun should handle 'each startup': https://superuser.com/a/302553/333316 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/17405182/2868801

Answer (score 66, accepted):

No, Windows command prompt history can't be saved when a session ends.

Comment: for real? how do you know this? Sorry for questioning you, I guess you are right but how can u know unless u programmed the damn thing ;)

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase :-) The Windows command interpreter ("cmd.exe") doesn't provide any support for saving/exporting/keeping history, of, if it does, Microsoft didn't document it and nobody was ever able to find it. You can of course try to work around that, like Sean suggested, but there's (or does appear to be) no built-in support for this.

Comment: You can press F7 to see a history list of the current session.

Comment: @jftuga, **Wow**, just wow, how did you know that?

Comment: *CURRENT* session is the keyword here.

Comment: You can see / save the history by running `doskey.exe /history` (that's also where the F7 shortcut comes from, BTW) but there's no way to load it back up in your next session.

Comment: cmd.exe has *nothing* to do with the console's (conhost.exe) cooked read, which supports basic line editing, history, aliases (matched only at the beginning of a line), and hotkeys such as F7. You can configure history support permanently in the console's default properties (`HKCU\Console`) or current properties (persisted in either a window-title subkey of `HKCU\Console` or a .lnk shortcut). Each concurrently attached process needs its own history buffer, which has a given max number of commands. Both max values can be set, as well as whether history buffers allow duplicate commands.

Comment: @ErykSun Would you mind putting it in an answer? I would like to set up what you say.

Comment: @Qwerty, I don't have a useful answer. The console API only supports reading the input command history for a given executable name, and it's an undocumented function that's only used by doskey.exe. There's no function to preload the input command history. At best, for your own process (not cmd.exe), you could do something unreliable to preload the contents: write it to console input via `WriteConsoleInputW` and read it back with `ReadConsoleW`. This is unreliable because it requires `ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT` mode, which makes it a visible replay, and the user could interfere by typing.

Comment: Unfortunately in Windows the history is not preserved between sessions.

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely possible to save the command line history when a session ends. See my answer: https://serverfault.com/a/1049766/114259

Comment: Windows - you never seem to stop me from being disappointed.

Answer (score 91):

Not natively but check out: http://mridgers.github.io/clink/ , makes cmd.exe much more productive. Quoting features from the project page:

```
Powerful Bash-like line editing from GNU's Readline library.
Superior path completion (TAB).
Paste from clipboard (Ctrl-V).
Support for the completion of executables/commands, and environment variables.
Undo/Redo (Ctrl-_ or Ctrl-X, Ctrl-U)
Improved command line history.
Persists across sessions.
Searchable (Ctrl-R and Ctrl-S).
History expansion (e.g. !!, !<string>, and !$).
Scriptable completion using Lua.
```

Comment: clink solved everything

Comment: Any plans to include it by default in Windows? :D

Comment: Can you set a `~/.inputrc` when using clink? (and do you know whether it can be used Console or anything?)

Comment: Apparently, see the doc https://github.com/mridgers/clink/blob/master/docs/clink.md.

Comment: ... except aliases. `clink` hates `doskey`; forget all of your years-long and carefully-assigned aliases. that's why i stopped to use it. though i miss all the features.

Comment: Thanks! Awesome tool ! Just wish it would also make Windows slightly great again by allowing us to delete files with long names - I went through every 'solution' in https://superuser.com/questions/45697/how-to-delete-a-file-in-windows-with-a-too-long-filename and none worked (deeply nested dirs)

Comment: The search function of Clink is practically useless. I want to use grep and regexes on history

Answer (score 26):

Massimo is correct that your command prompt history does not persist across sessions.  You could manually grab this before closing your prompt by typing **doskey /history > history.txt**

Or... you could use [PowerShell](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=968930) as your CMD prompt, and follow [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209023331/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/powershell/archive/2006/07/01/perserving-command-history-across-sessions.aspx) to persist your history across sessions.

Answer (score 19):

You can use **[clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/)**.

> Clink combines the native Windows shell cmd.exe with the powerful command line editing features of the GNU Readline library, which provides rich completion, history, and line-editing capabilities.

Easiest way to install clink is using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). Once you install chocolatey, you can install clink by typing

```
choco install clink
```

Starting from the next time you start cmd.exe, it should store history across sessions.

Comment: Finally decided to give `Chocolatey` a shot because of this post. Installation was as easy as of `brew` in macOS. And now I have a Bash-like command prompt in Windows!

Comment: Yes must say `Chocolatey` is definitely awesome, takes `some` of the worry about downloading the 'proper' installation file

Comment: I need to install [chrisant996/clink](https://github.com/chrisant996/clink) as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/issues/568) to make it work on Windows 11.

Comment: I've read through this post but do not understand how to get clink to keep a global cmdhistory. Depite installing clink, every time I open a cmd window, I cannot get commands from prior sessions. help>

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to save the current history to file,

```
`$ doskey /history > somefile.txt`
```

But it seems there is no way to load it back as history.
It is possible only to use a command line argument to load and execute all lines,

`cmd.exe /K somefile.txt`

, what can be useful to load a list of doskey macros.
This invocation could be included in a shortcut so you don't need to type it everytime; [this reference has some additional info on this approach](http://devblog.point2.com/2010/05/14/setup-persistent-aliases-macros-in-windows-command-prompt-cmd-exe-using-doskey/).

There is a similar question [on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/257855/keep-cmd-exe-command-history-between-sessions) that bring some alternatives, including [clink](http://code.google.com/p/clink/), as suggested by @RobertBak.

Comment: Hmm, to load it back into history, wouldn't you simply need to save it to a .bat file and run it?

Comment: @Pacerier running the commands again would surely include them back in the history, but it likely would have large side-effects. Imagine that you delete some files through the shell and then recreate them outside the shell through a long and painful process. Reloading the history through your procedure would unexpectedly delete the files again.

Comment: @Pacerier you realize "run it" does mean executing all those commands, right? It's not simply loading them into history, but actually letting them have some effects on your system.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it's possible**

If all you want to do is save your command line history at the end of every session, here's a simple way to do it:

As other answers indicated, `doskey` allows you to list the command line history for the current session. It also allows you to create macros.

This simple macro will save the command line history when you exit a `CMD` session:

```
doskey exit=(echo/ ^& echo **** %date% %time% ****) $g$g %USERPROFILE%\commands.log ^& doskey /history $g$g %USERPROFILE%\commands.log ^& ECHO Command history saved, exiting ^& exit $*
```

This creates a macro that remaps the `EXIT` command to copy the command line history into your user profile folder (e.g., `C:\Users\yourname\commands.log`). Unfortunately, you won't be able to easily go back to any of these entries by pressing the up arrow, but you can examine the file at any point to see what you did in the past.

**Autoloading**

So that's the easy part. The tricky part is autoloading that doskey macro when you start a new command session. The short and dangerous answer is to just add it to the REGISTRY in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`. Anything you put in this entry will be run when you start a `CMD` session.

While that will work, it will definitely create unexpected side effects when doing any kind of scripting*.

**So here's how I do it:**

Create a file called `autoexec.bat` and store it in your profile folder (e.g., `C:\Users\yourname\autoexec.bat`). Then change the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` to this:

```
IF EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\autoexec.bat" (CALL "%USERPROFILE%\autoexec.bat")
```

So yes, this batch file will run every time a `CMD` session is opened, but we'll do a trick to make sure it doesn't run in any subprocesses. Here is what you put in the `autoexec.bat` file:

```
@echo off
if "%AUTOEXEC%" EQU "1" goto :eof
SET AUTOEXEC=1
echo Loading macros.

rem  remap exit command to save a copy of the command line history to a log before exiting.
DOSKEY exit=(echo/ ^& echo **** %date% %time% ****) $g$g %USERPROFILE%\commands.log ^& doskey /history $g$g %USERPROFILE%\commands.log ^& ECHO Command history saved, exiting ^& exit $*
```

**How does this avoid those unexpected side effects?**

All we're doing is creating an environment variable called `AUTOEXEC`. Then, when any subsequent subprocesses open a command session, they will run into the second line and immediately exit the script! This is because subprocesses automatically inherit the environment variables from the parent process.

**But wait, there's more!**

This allows you to add as many macros as you want to your command session. For example:

```
rem  review previous command line entries:
DOSKEY history=notepad %USERPROFILE%\commands.log

rem  copy the current directory to the clipboard
DOSKEY cc=cd^|clip ^& echo %%CD%% copied to clipboard

rem  etc!
```

Now you've got all the macros you can eat, *and* you're saving your command line session each time. But remember, if you don't explicitly type `exit`, the history won't be saved. Closing the window with the mouse won't work here.

Hope this helps!

* because batch subprocesses often open a second copy of `CMD` which will run this command again and again, from slowing everything down to other unforseen issues.

Answer (score 2):

I propose using Cygwin with Windows Terminal. It may not be exactly what you want but it works quite well for me. It also probably has some issues that I haven't discovered just yet.

You can integrate Cygwin with Windows Terminal and use ZSH shell with it to have a working command history that survives closing the terminal window. You can also reverse search the command history with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Since you're using ZSH, you can also install useful stuff like Oh My Zsh along with plugins like `zsh-autosuggestions` and `zsh-syntax-highlighting` to make life easier.

My setup looks like this:

[image: Cygwin with ZSH]

1. Once you have [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) installed to `C:/cygwin64/` integrate it with Windows Terminal by editing its `settings.json` file. To do this, open Windows Terminal and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (comma). The file should open in your default text/code editor.
2. Look for the `profiles` section and add this to the end of the `list` array:

```
{
    "colorScheme": "One Half Dark",
    "commandline": "C:/cygwin64/Cygwin.bat",
    "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}",
    "hidden": false,
    "icon": "C:/cygwin64/Cygwin.ico",
    "name": "Cygwin",
    "tabColor": "#3CB371"
}
```

The section of the file should look something like this when you're done:

```
    "profiles": 
    {
        "defaults": {},
        "list": 
        [
            {
                "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Windows PowerShell"
            },
            {
                "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Command Prompt"
            },
            {
                "guid": "{b453ae62-4e3d-5e58-b989-0a998ec441b8}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Azure Cloud Shell",
                "source": "Windows.Terminal.Azure"
            },
            {
                "guid": "{f9ceaf27-504c-58d7-927c-d1d6a7ac7d3c}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS",
                "source": "CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_79rhkp1fndgsc"
            },
            {
                "guid": "{17bf3de4-5353-5709-bcf9-835bd952a95e}",
                "hidden": true,
                "name": "Ubuntu-22.04",
                "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl"
            },
            {
                "colorScheme": "One Half Dark",
                "commandline": "C:/cygwin64/Cygwin.bat",
                "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}",
                "hidden": false,
                "icon": "C:/cygwin64/Cygwin.ico",
                "name": "Cygwin",
                "tabColor": "#3CB371"
            }
        ]
    },
```

3. Save the file and open Windows Terminal and click on the **<kbd>˅</kbd>** button and select **Cygwin** or press the shortcut key associated with that profile
4. Open the Cygwin installer and make sure you have the following packages installed: **lynx, wget, tar, git, vim**
5. Within the Cygwin terminal, install `apt-cyg` with

```
lynx -source rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > apt-cyg
install apt-cyg /bin
```

6. Now install ZSH

```
apt-cyg install zsh
```

7. If you want, you can install [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) along with [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/blob/master/INSTALL.md#oh-my-zsh) and [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/blob/master/INSTALL.md#oh-my-zsh) plugins. Make sure you set up your `~/.zshrc` file so these plugins are enabled.

```
git clone https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh.git ~/.oh-my-zsh
cp ~/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template ~/.zshrc
```

8. The final step is to create a new `.bat` file that will be called when Cygwin terminal is selected within Windows Terminal. Create a new `Cygwin-ZSH.bat` file at this location: `C:/cygwin64/Cygwin-ZSH.bat` and then paste the following into it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set TERM=
cd /d "%~dp0bin" && .\zsh --login -i
```

9. Open Windows Terminal's `settings.json` file and modify the **Cygwin** profile entry to use the new `Cygwin-ZSH.bat` file for the Cygwin terminal (See Step 2)

```
{
    "colorScheme": "One Half Dark",
    "commandline": "C:/cygwin64/Cygwin-ZSH.bat",
    "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}",
    "hidden": false,
    "icon": "C:/cygwin64/Cygwin.ico",
    "name": "Cygwin",
    "tabColor": "#3CB371"
}
```

10. If you want, make Cygwin the default profile to use whenever Windows Terminal is launched. To do this, open Windows Terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (comma) to open the **Settings** page and under **Default profile**, select **Cygwin**

That's it. You should be able to access the commands you typed previously (after the Cygwin profile was installed and set to default) with the `history` command now.

The first time I launch a Cygwin terminal, it takes a while to load but any new Terminal windows/tabs launched after that were fast to load.

---

Many thanks to these articles which is where I found out about this:

1. https://dev.to/vuong/let-s-add-cygwin-into-windows-terminal-and-customize-it-for-development-looks-1hp8
2. https://medium.com/@alllexsm/how-to-install-z-shell-zsh-on-cygwin-dd9ee380d783

Answer (score 1):

Command History: 
    To enable a command history (that can be accessed using the up and
    down arrow keys) just execute doskey at the command
    prompt.  For example, to create a command history of 100 elements:

```
doskey /listsize=100
```

ref:https://users.cs.jmu.edu/bernstdh/web/common/help/ntshell.php

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all??

Comment: Not works on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

[clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/) is nice and the author publishes a chocolatey package on every release, however I would suggest DeepBlueCLI.

You can use https://github.com/sans-blue-team/DeepBlueCLI to set-up Windows Security Event ID 4688.

For PowerShell, DeepBlueCLI also uses module logging (PowerShell event 4013) and script block logging (4104). It does not use transcription.

The added benefit is that it logs the hash of the command line exe in AppLocker event log. Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/command-line-process-auditing

Also, because this solution uses the Windows Event Log infrastructure, you can query it through WMI or PowerShell `Get-EventLog`.  With clink, you have to learn another tool in order to detect system- or network-wide patterns of behavior.

Comment: event 4688 is the key, and that is the central store how Windows record all executed commands.   all other tools is just reading looking for this event.   thanks.   But by default is it not enable:   https://www.itprotoday.com/strategy/understanding-and-enabling-command-line-auditing

Answer (score 1):

you could also install tabby (https://tabby.sh/). or use **(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath**

Answer (score 0):

To save command history:

```
doskey /history > history.dos
```

To reference commands:

```
cls & type history.dos | find /v /n ""
```

This method won't change the command history of current session

To add the current session command history to the last save file:

```
doskey /history >> history.dos
```

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 now includes alternative and better shells ('terminals' as they call them).

1. Windows Terminal, i think i installed it via the built in store. Once installed just press start and search for Terminal or do Start>Run>wt. This includes persistent command history.
2. Ubuntu shell, You can install Windows Subsystem for Linux and Ubuntu, both of these come from the built in store. If you know unix then having access to all the usual  bash utilities and syntax is very handy and of course command history is persistent.

Comment: How do you enable persistent command history in `wt`? Each time I start a new terminal session it starts with empty history (arror up doesn't yield anything). How to search that history (Ctrl+R doesn't work here)?

Comment: Shells and terminals have nothing to do with each other. Windows terminal is a terminal like xterm, konsole, gnome-terminal... in Linux, or conhost.exe in Windows which is the old terminal. A shell OTOH is a thing that *attaches* to some terminal to work. PowerShell, cmd, bash, ksh, zsh... are example of shells. Since Windows terminal is a terminal, it obviously can't store the shell's history, so if you use cmd you still won't be able to store any thing

Comment: @phuclv COMMAND was the default terminal (using CTTY) as well as the default shell.  And in Linux, there is still a thing called "Secure Shell", (ssh), which doesn't "attach" to a "terminal." SSH doesn't have a persistent history, but that's not because it's a 'terminal' or a 'shell' -- lots of terminals have persistent history, and lots of shells don't.

Comment: @user165568 how can the terminal have shell command history? It only has scroll back history